# Data not showing on Firebase, Using V-data-table Vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

The data is not showing, I do not know how to push the value from the firebase to the v-data-table values. Here is my code.

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <h2 class="subheading mx-5">Subject</h2>
    <v-btn block color="primary mt-5" @click="enrollSubjects()">Enroll Subjects</v-btn>
    <v-container class="my-5">
      <template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            Courses
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-text-field v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-data-table v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="courses" show-select :single-select="singleSelect" item-key="descrip_title" :search="search">

          </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import db from '@/firebase/init'
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
      singleSelect: false,
      subjects: [],
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {text: 'Control No.', value: 'controlno'},
        {text: 'Course No.', value: 'courseno'},
        {text: 'Descriptive Title', value: 'descrip_title'},
        {text: 'Schedule(In)', value: 'schedin'},
        {text: 'Schedule(Out)', value: 'schedout'},
        {text: 'Room No.', value: 'roomno'},
        {text: 'Days', value: 'days'},
        {text: 'Units', value: 'units'}
      ],
      courses: []
    }
  },
  methods:{
    enrollSubjects(){
      if(this.selected === this.selected){
        this.$swal({
          title: 'No Course Selected', 
          text: 'Please select course/s',
          type: 'error'
        })
      }
    },
    created(){
      db.collection('masterlist_courses').get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let course = doc.data()
          course.id = doc.id
          this.courses.push(course)
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am practicing in firebase and vuetify, I do not know how to push this to the value of the v-data-table. I am having hard time and its not showing anything to the datatable and also there is no error. It's not saying anything after I code the data in the firebase not displaying

Comment: Do you receive the data? What happens if you just output "courses" like this: {{ this.courses }} ?

Comment: im not sure. I checked on alert it just say [object, object]

Comment: Maybe have a look into item-text and item-value in the <v-data-table> component

Comment: I dont know the problem but when i put the created on a button, it shows the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use one of the vue.js [life cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) to trigger the fetch before the component is mounted.

For example the `created` hook can be used to "run code after an instance is created", as follows:

```
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import db from '@/firebase/init'
export default {
  name: 'dashboard',
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
      singleSelect: false,
      subjects: [],
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {text: 'Control No.', value: 'controlno'},
        {text: 'Course No.', value: 'courseno'},
        {text: 'Descriptive Title', value: 'descrip_title'},
        {text: 'Schedule(In)', value: 'schedin'},
        {text: 'Schedule(Out)', value: 'schedout'},
        {text: 'Room No.', value: 'roomno'},
        {text: 'Days', value: 'days'},
        {text: 'Units', value: 'units'}
      ],
      courses: []
    }
  },
  methods:{
    enrollSubjects(){
      if(this.selected === this.selected){
        this.$swal({
          title: 'No Course Selected', 
          text: 'Please select course/s',
          type: 'error'
        })
      }
    }
  },
  created: function() {
      db.collection('masterlist_courses').get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let course = doc.data()
          course.id = doc.id
          this.courses.push(course)
        })
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Note that if the query to Firestore is going to take some time, you could display a [spinner](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress-circular) and hide it when the query is done, i.e. in the callback passed to `then()`, after `snapshot.forEach()`.

Comment: @PeterParker Hello, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Yes sir, thank you so much! Helped me a lot. Thank you soooo muchh againnn

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what items should be shown. You have only defined your headers so far. Try it like this for every header you have.

```
                    <template v-slot:item.controlno="{ item }">
                        {{ item.controlno }}
                    </template>
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: By doing `:items="courses"` in the Vuetify `v-data-table` component, the elements in the `courses` array will be rendered in the table, see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables